# Android app using camera, photo disappears after screen rotation

Tags: android, camera, rotation, photo

The purpose of the app is to snap a photo and have it appear on the screen afterwards. I have locked the screen rotation to portrait, but after the photo is snapped and attached to the app screen, the phone's screen is able to rotate again and if that happens, the image disappears. How do I fix that? Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static String logtag = "CameraApp";
private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
private Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button cameraButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
}

private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        takePhoto(v);
    }
};

public void takePhoto(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_camera);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Its a quick fix.. it doent really solve the problem but u can stop the screen from changing orientation by adding this code to your manifest where your MainActivity is located.. just add this line..

```
<activity
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        ...>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

When the change the screen orientation, the system will restart the activity (calls onDestroy() and then onCreate()). So I believe you need to set the image again after the restart.

This link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html has some helpful info on how to handle this. The easiest way would probably be to store the image uri in the onSaveInstanceState() and then restore the image in onRestoreInstanceState().

Answer (score 0):

set Id for each of your views to prevent loss of data when screen change orientation

1. create an xml file in values and call it ids.xml
2. create your ids there like this

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <item name="button_1_id" type="id"/>
       <item name="button_2_id" type="id"/>
       <item name="imageView_id" type="id"/>
       ....
   </resources>
   ```
3. Set id :

   ```
   button_1.setId(R.id.button_1_id);
   ...
   ```